# Can I download and play games from a friend's PSN account on a PS4?

Tags: ps4, psn

So this is the situation:

- My brother received a PS4 on his birthday.
- He doesn't have a PS+ account, and I don't have a PS4, so I activated it as my primary PS4.
- Based on what I've read on the FAQ, any user can play my digital games and do online gaming since I activated the system as my primary PS4.
- A friend offered his account so we can play his digital games. He has a primary PS4 activated.

The question is, can we really play his games without any issues? For example, can we download GTAV from his account and play it using any account on our PS4?

Comment: Afaik no :/ but I don't use consoles.

Comment: If you download gta V on his ps4, any account can play gta v on the ps4 were it's downloaded and installed as long as the account which own GTA V is logged into PSN which means you'd have to log into that account and save the PSN password to auto login

Comment: Ah, I failed to read your comment. This answers my question on my comment on your answer. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Sharing your digital games, apps, and other downloads with your family
> and friends is possible with the Primary and Non-Primary Account [...]
>
> In this example we are using Ethan and Katie who both have their own
> PSN account IDs.  Ethan also has a bunch of digital games which he
> bought on the PSN Store using his PSN account. Objective: He wants to
> share these digital games with Katie, so this is what he does:

[image: Explanation on how to share psn games]

> Both Ethan and Katie can now play the same game at the same time on
> PS4 (A) and PS4 (B) with no restrictions.
>
> Benefits of activating a PS4 as Primary:
>
> - Anyone who uses your Primary PS4™ system can enjoy applications you
>   purchase from the PlayStation®Store. Other users on the system can
>   also enjoy some PlayStation Plus benefits from that account, even if
>   that user is not logged in.
>
> Limitations:
>
> - This method of sharing only applies to digital games and apps. The    sharing of disc games will still require you to physically lend your discs to others.
> - When you log into a non-primary PS4 with your PSN ID, you will need    an active Internet connection so that games and apps from your PSN account can be authenticated by PSN.
> - You can activate only one PS4 system as primary per PSN account.
> - You can deactivate a PS4 system only from that system.

The whole explanation and the picture belongs to [**gripitaustralia**](http://www.gripitaustralia.com.au/blogs/the-gamers-telegraph/35578241-sharing-games-on-your-ps4-using-the-primary-non-primary-account-method).

There is an official article about activating and deactivating you Primary PS4 on [**playstation.com**](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5059/%7E/activate-%2F-deactivate-primary-ps4).

Comment: For example, if in Ethan's PS4 there's an account for his brother, say NathanABC111, can Nathan play Ethan's PS4 games using his own account, or should he use Ethan's account to play the games? Either way your answer solves my issue, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: as long as the ps4 is set as primary console on ethans account, nethan will able to play ethans games

Comment: Actually, following this example, any other user on Ethan's secundary system won't be able to play his games. *Katie's sister* is the one that can play Ethan's game on her own account in Ethan's primary (in Katie's house), if Nathan wants to play Ethan's game he has to use Ethan's account on Ethan's device, or if he (Nathan) wants to play with his own account he would have to go to Katie's house to play in Katie's system (Ethan's primary system)