# 3 PS4's in the house with 3 separate psn plus accounts

Tags: psn

So we have 3 PS4's in the house (My husband, child 1 & child 2) They all have their own PSN Plus accounts. Instead of buying 3 PSN plus 12 month subscriptions can I get a family subscription that will cover them all?

Comment: The answer is yes and no.. you'll be able to use ps plus on 2 consoles but it wont work for 3..[**see my answer here**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232132/can-i-download-and-play-games-from-a-friends-psn-account-on-a-ps4/232151#232151) that dont fit 100% your question but it's the same for ps+

Answer (score 3):

No, you will have to buy separate subscriptions for each account. There is no "family pass".*

*You *could* game share, however. I'm not going to persuade or dissuade you from it, as it has its pros and cons. See Nitro.de's comment on your question (his answer to another question) on how that works, as it is a separate issue from what you're asking.