# My PS4 doesn't work with online games but Netflix works online

Tags: ps4

I'm going through a problem, so recently I had my birthday and received a PS4 as a gift.. big problem is that I can download, watch online shows(Netflix, YouTube, etc.), file share, see which friends are online. But the problem is that I can't play any game with online features, or I can't complete the in-game installation e.g can't finish the Vader mini game in Battlefront due to Installation or I can't finish the NBA 2K17 mini game due to installation and online features....

- I have restarted my PS4 more than once to factory version.
- Have deleted game data and re-downloaded.
- Restarted PS4
- Turned it on and turned it off

I can't find any solution can I please grab some help guys?

Comment: Also these games are pre owned and the others are digital which are also from another person so I don't know if that's the problem??

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't have an active PS+ account which is required for online gaming, whereas Netflix is third party and doesn't require an active PS+ account.

Physical game copies will have no issue playing on any PS4 you put them in, or else rental stores would not be able to rent out games.

You might run into issues playing the digital games (you mention these are "pre-owned") as those are licensed per the PS+ account that bought the games. To play these digital games the PS4 must be set to be the PS+ accounts primary system, or that account must be logged in and used to play the game.

Comment: For a better explanation on digital game sharing [see this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232132/can-i-download-and-play-games-from-a-friends-psn-account-on-a-ps4?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

You need PS Plus Subscription I guess.